# Actualización de varias webs a la vez

Tags: wordpress, crm

Estoy buscando la forma de desarrollar una web (A) que sirva de nexo a varias webs ya existentes (B,C,D). El objetivo es introducir los contenidos una única vez en A y que en las otras webs se integre automáticamente su parte de contenido correspondiente.

El problema: las webs B,C,D están desarrolladas en distintos frameworks y CMS (Joomla, Drupal, Liferay con Bootstrap).

Había pensado en desarrollar la web A en Wordpress y utilizar un CRM externo que centralice la parte de contenidos común. ¿Alguien sabe si esto es posible?

Gracias.

Comment: Tú quieres por ejemplo crear un post en A y que ese post sea repetido en B, C y D?

Comment: Exacto, pero con un matiz... todos los posts se crearán en A pero sólo algunos de ellos irán en B, otros en C y otros en D. Es decir, en A están todas las categorías; en B, C y D la categoría que corresponda a cada uno de ellos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría en una de ellas, la de contenidos, un módulo tipo services (en Drupal ya existe) que permita acceder al contenido por json o xml, luego en las otras, programas otro módulo que lea dichos contenidos remotos para mostrarlos localmente. Lógicamente no te voy a crear yo los módulos, pero la idea te puede valer para implementarlo tu mismo.

Otra opción sería instalar el Drupal en modo multisite (creo que wordpress también tiene la opción), pero si no voy errado, esto solo vale si todos los gestores son iguales.

Mira el tema de services de Drupal en: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/services/

Si quieres engancharte a Drupal de forma manual:

```
<?php
chdir("/var/www/dominio.com/web/admin/"); // Ruta del Drupal
require_once "./includes/bootstrap.inc";
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
?>
```

Si quieres engancharte a wordpress:

```
<?php
require './admin/wp-load.php';
?>
```

Comment: Me has abierto una opción. No conozco la forma de hacerlo, pero investigaré sobre esta línea.

Comment: Prueba algo y si no te sale, nos pasas el código y lo miramos.